# How to fold errors checks in go in vim?

Tags: vim, go

In my code I have a lot of such checks:

```
if err != nil {
  // foo
}
```

How to easily fold them in vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick `:g/\s*if err /normal jva{zf`

Comment: This worked like a charm thanks! 

Just to break it down a bit: `:g/\s*` looks like a global search for the pattern matching `if err` not sure what the `/normal` flag does here if could help explain that. And then `jva{zf` does the folding portion.

Comment: I also set my foldmethod to manual using this command `:set foldmethod='manual'`, if that helps anyone. Read more about fold methods here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Folding